# C# i want to insert a space before and after symbols such as "+ - * /" in a text box

Tags: c#, regex

C# i want to insert a space before and after symbols such as "+ - * /" in a text box

Eg. before

```
85+89/56
```

after

```
85 + 89 / 56
```

Comment: You have tagged this regex, so you have something already? Please share what you have.

Comment: What are your affords so far? What did you try?

Comment: You can achieve that even without Regex, you just have 4 symbols. Use String.Replace. If you plan to use regex, it is really basic: `[+*/-]`.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: textBox.Text = Regex.Replace(textBox.Text, @"\*(?! |$)", " * ");

Comment: that is what i have, however i don't fully understand Regex, but this doesn't check for space before the symbol...  and it only takes one symbol at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´d suggest a simple one-liner:

```
myString = "85+89/56".Replace("+", " + ").Replace("-", " - ").Replace("/", " / ")
```

If you need more characters to be replaced build a method:

```
string ReplaceSpecialCharacters(string theString, string c, string replacement) 
{
    return theString.Replace(c, replacement);
}
```

As mentioned in the comments if there already are whitespaces within the input you may simply delete them before using `String-Replace(" ", "")`

EDIT: To be more usefull the method might be extended:

```
string ReplaceSpecialCharacters(string theString, string[] searchStrings, string delimiter) 
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(theString);
    for(var search in searchString) 
        builder.Append(theString.Replace(search, delimiter+ search + delimiter);

    return builder.ToString();

}
```

Comment: @ataravati OP did not mention this, however I added a comment

Comment: OP did not mention this, but it's obvious.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do this with Regex. This will also remove extra space if there is any:

```
var text = "85+89/56";
var pattern = @"\s*([+*/-])\s*";

text = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, " $1 ");
```

Comment: Then, can I ask why you didn't choose it as the correct answer?